# MySQL - Optimising an update function for performance reasons

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to go through the database one row at a time. The aim is to go through all the entries in a database table to update a column.

**simplified DB table**

| id | data | ratings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jsonstring* | ratingstring* |

Note: There are over 200,000 entries.

**(*)jsonstring**
`{"ID":78,"post_author":1,"active":1,"a_rating_users":71,"a_rating_score":278,"a_rating_avarage":"3.92","t_rating_users":6,"t_rating_score":19,"t_rating_avarage":"3.17","r_rating_users":5,"r_rating_score":22,"r_rating_avarage":"4.40"}`

**(*)ratingstring**

`{"d":{"r":"1","c":1,"a":1},"t":{"r":5,"c":1,"a":5},"p":{"r":5,"c":1,"a":5}}`

**data** are CHARACTER SET: utf8 and TYPE: TEXT

**ratings** are CHARACTER SET:  utf8 and TYPE: Varchar

My current approach:
I get all the data and iterate it with a foreach loop. Since it still has to
decode the string into a JSON for each entry, it takes a long time.

How can I optimise it? One consideration was to read each row individually from
the database, modify it and save it. But I don't know if this would work and how
to move the database pointer to the next entry.

Comment: Please provide precise, not approximate, data. Precise MySQL version, complete CREATE TABLE, data example (3-5 rows as INSERT INTO), and table-formatted final data state or query output with detailed explanations. *One consideration was to read each row individually from the database, modify it and save it.* This is "infinite work" approach...

Comment: You should filter the records on database layer first. So that add `WHERE` clause on your query. Or, you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to limit the number of records first.

Comment: "... the data is in a JSON string. But this does not play a further role in my question." If I understand correctly, next sentence indicates that it plays the main role in your question.

Comment: Are you using JSON datatype for your columns? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: @Hendrik It does matter but even without JSON I find the approach of sending all the data to the application and then iterating over-demensioned. For example memory. Therefore, I suspect that one line by line and would be 200,000 times better. But I can also be wrong. Therefore my question to you experts.

Comment: @Hendrik I will updated my question soon and provide this information too. But i didnt use json datatype. the field is simple varchar.

Comment: @KrassVerpeilt Why did you choose `VARCHAR(...)` over `JSON` data type to store a JSON string.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa 1) I think because I did not know better and I still have too little experience with database optimization. (not only here ;-) 2) Because the original database was SQLite.

Comment: This update is not one which I have asked for. I (personally) cannot use it.

Comment: @KrassVerpeilt - The `JSON` _datatype_ was introduced in 5.7.8; what version are you running?

Comment: Do you need to "update" _every_ row?  Is the table being inserted into while you do the process?  How often do you need to run this process?  (I have different techniques depending on your answers.)